# Move image around browser window and bounce back on striking side wall

Tags: javascript, html

I am in phase of learning javascript. I'm working on a simple javascript (purely javascript without jquery etc) program for moving images across browser. As far as i understand, i can move image to left or right by addition or subtraction in `img.style.left` or `img.style.right` - But i need to know how can i bounce back image when it hits browser sidebar ?

So image goes first to left and when it hits browser side wall it rebounds back to right and on hitting right side wall, it again starts moving to left.

Kindly help me with this. Thanks in advance

Comment: if you wanna use pure JS no Jquery the using `cubic-bezier` in css and add class dynamically when it hit the right or left...

Comment: @AshishMishra: See this JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/shumail/ny9wK/1/
i think window.load is not working here , you can try this on browser. my image goes straight beyond the side.

Comment: yes you have to apply control on it by using `if(parseInt(imgObj.style.left) <=parseInt( window.innerWidth)-50 )` after that in `else` you add `class` in which you define bounce effect!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an answer in pure JavaScript, that is pretty straight-forward.

Basically, you'll want an interval (or a timeout that restarts itself over and over). Then, you grab the left value of the style (or the `offsetLeft`). You then add the direction * the distance per "tick" to the position, check for collision, and reverse direction as needed.

The code example below is pretty well commented.

A key to this is: don't set left or right. Pick one, and only control it. Trying to control both at once would drive you insane. Most of the time you'll want to control "left" since it is equivalent to "x" in a lot of languages (which is generally what you control for horizontal position).

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dMJ2F/1/

```
var parent = document.getElementById('container'); // Element that holds the mover
var mover = document.getElementById('mover'); // The mover, can be anything
var dir = 1; // The direction we are moving... 1 is right, -1 is left.
var dist = 10; // The distance we move each "tick"

// The ID will let us stop it later if we want.
var intervalId = setInterval(function() {
    // Get the left, remove the "px" from the end and convert it to an integer.
    var posX = parseInt(mover.style.left.replace(/px$/, '')) || 0;

    // Add dir * dist
    posX += dir * dist;

    // If we are moving right and we've gone over the right edge...
    if (dir == 1 && posX + mover.offsetWidth > parent.offsetWidth) {
        // only move right to the edge...
        posX -= posX + mover.offsetWidth - parent.offsetWidth;
        // and change direction.
        dir *= -1
    // If we are moving left and we've gone over the left edge...
    } else if (dir == -1 && posX < 0) {
        // stop at zero...
        posX = 0;
        // and change direction...
        dir *= -1;
    }

    // Set the new position
    mover.style.left = posX + "px";
}, 100); // this number is how many milliseconds in between each move.
// Smaller interval time means smoother movement but slower performance.
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use CSS3 animations:

```
#wrapper {
    position: relative;
    margin-right: 50px;
}
#ball {
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    background: blue;
    border-radius: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    animation: animate 4s linear 0s infinite alternate;
}
@keyframes animate {
    from { left: 100%; }
    to { left: 0; }
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/tRV5h/)

Answer (score 0):

You want to keep track of speed and direction, mainly, for this.

There's two ways to approach this:

1. Using `requestAnimationFrame` to move the image as well as check to see whether it's hit the site of the browser,
2. Using `CSS3 animation` (manipulation from JavaScript). Set a destination x (being the edge of the browser) once that animation is finished, do a reversed animation to the other side.

Check these resources out:

- http://css-tricks.com/controlling-css-animations-transitions-javascript/
- http://css-tricks.com/using-requestanimationframe/

Answer (score 0):

While [samanime's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22076732/move-image-around-browser-window-and-bounce-back-on-striking-side-wall/22077166#22077166) answer is correct, you should use `requestAnimationFrame` over `setInterval` if you just want to have it draw on the next repaint. There is performance improvements over the other methods listed in the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame).

I've modified samanime's code below to use `requestAnimationFrame`.

```js
var parent = document.getElementById('container'); // Element that holds the mover
var mover = document.getElementById('mover'); // The mover, can be anything
var dir = 1; // The direction we are moving... 1 is right, -1 is left.
var dist = 10; // The distance we move each "tick"

// The ID will let us stop it later if we want.
function draw() {
    // Get the left, remove the "px" from the end and convert it to an integer.
    var posX = parseInt(mover.style.left.replace(/px$/, '')) || 0;
    
    // Add dir * dist
    posX += dir * dist;
    
    // If we are moving right and we've gone over the right edge...
    if (dir == 1 && posX + mover.offsetWidth > parent.offsetWidth) {
        // only move right to the edge...
        posX -= posX + mover.offsetWidth - parent.offsetWidth;
        // and change direction.
        dir *= -1
    // If we are moving left and we've gone over the left edge...
    } else if (dir == -1 && posX < 0) {
        // stop at zero...
        posX = 0;
        // and change direction...
        dir *= -1;
    }
    
    // Set the new position
    mover.style.left = posX + "px";
    window.requestAnimationFrame(draw); // Re-draw
}

window.requestAnimationFrame(draw);
```

```css
#container {
    position: relative;
}

#mover {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id="mover"></div>
</div>
```